# how to eliminate automatic indentation in pseudo code

Tags: indentation, algorithmicx, algorithmic, pseudocode, algpseudocode

In the code, one of the lines has an automatic indentation. How can I eliminate the indentation(it is the line after the command "\Endwhile")?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\Require Dataset $D = \{ (x(t_i), x(t_i), x(t_i))\}$
\While{$N \neq 0$}

\EndWhile \\

last line with indentation (How to make it no indented)

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The space is essentially reserved for the line number.  What is the status of this extra line?  Is it part of the algorithm, a comment, or... Is the last line of environment?

Answer (score 4):

A quick hack:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\Require Dataset $D = \{ (x(t_i), x(t_i), x(t_i))\}$
\While{$N \neq 0$}

\EndWhile \\
\hspace{-3ex} %% <-- a quick hack
last line with indentation (How to make it no indented)
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```